# Vertex upload file: BodyHandler methods not working

Tags: kotlin, vert.x, vertex, vertx-verticle

I want to upload avatars. My endpoints are set with OpenAPI3RouterFactory(api.yaml file). 

 ***api.yaml:***

```
#other endpoints

/api/v1/upload-avatar:
  post:
    summary: Uploading avatars endpoint
    operationId: upload-avatar
    tags:
      - sign up
      - registration

#other ones
```

***HandlerVerticle.kt:***

```
//OpenApi3Router is set
//other endpoints
routerFactory.addHandlerByOperationId("upload-avatar", BodyHandler.create().setDeleteUploadedFilesOnEnd(true).setUploadsDirectory("mp-upload").setMergeFormAttributes(true))
routerFactory.addHandlerByOperationId("upload-avatar", { routingContext -> 
        val fileUploadSet = routingContext.fileUploads()
        val fileUploadIterator = fileUploadSet.iterator()
        while (fileUploadIterator.hasNext()) {
            val fileUpload = fileUploadIterator.next()
            val uploadedFile = vertx.fileSystem().readFileBlocking(fileUpload.uploadedFileName())

            try {
                val fileName = URLDecoder.decode(fileUpload.fileName(), "UTF-8")
                vertx.fileSystem().writeFileBlocking(fileName , uploadedFile)
                routingContext.response().end()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }


        }
})

//other routes
```

when I upload the image it uploads successful, but in server side vertx creates wrong upload directory, and it doesn't delete temporary uploaded files. Can anyone help me?

Comment: And where does it upload instead?

Comment: It's uploading in src/main/java/<package-name>/file-uploads

Comment: Using the default directory then. Can you add which VertX OpenAPI V3 library you're using in your Maven/Gradle?

Comment: compile "io.vertx:vertx-web-api-contract: 3.5.1"

Comment: FYI, my PR was merged and should be in VertX 3.6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this should be considered a bug, or something intentional, but...

`OpenAPI3RouterFactoryImpl.getRouter()` [always overrides BodyHandler](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-web/blob/de1080d633e935e480490669a6c557b616edd468/vertx-web-api-contract/src/main/java/io/vertx/ext/web/api/contract/openapi3/impl/OpenAPI3RouterFactoryImpl.java#L195)

No matter what you set there before.

I opened a new issue for now: https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-web/issues/860